# Does cv.glmnet in R accept binary factor features?

Tags: r, glmnet

I tried to develop a GLMNET model and used cv.glmnet to use $lambdamin for prediction. I converted all categorical variables into dummy variables. Since they are all binary variables, so I convert them from numeric back to factors. I didn't get any error.

What happens if I feed factor variables into GLMNET? Would the model ignore them?

Thx.

```
#---------------------------- Train ---------------------------------------------#    
cv.glmnet.fit <- cv.glmnet(x = x.train, y = y.train, nfolds = 10, type.measure = "auc", alpha =0.5, family = "binomial")

# print out cross validation summary
max(cv.glmnet.fit$cvm)
summary(cv.glmnet.fit$cvm)
plot(cv.glmnet.fit)

# Check lambda.min
cv.glmnet.fit$lambda.min


#---------------------------- Predict ---------------------------------------------#
# Choose the lambda with the minimum CV-estimated loss:
cv.glmnet.lambda.min.pred <- predict(cv.glmnet.fit,
                                     s = cv.glmnet.fit$lambda.min,
                                     newx = x.test, type="response")
```